# According to the bible, where did egypt arise from?

Tags: bible

How was Egypt created according to the bible? Was it started by descendants of Cain? The descendants of Seth started the Israelites and Canaanites if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about World history not addressed in the Bible.

Comment: @bruisedreed: In which case it's a simple verse request, which is also off-topic.

Comment: The Flood ended the line of Cain; and only 8 survived in the lineage of Seth that being Noah his three sons and their wives. So you are mistaken in associating any descendent from Cain. All current Nations were the result of the dispersion at the tower of Babel. As with any other subject in Biblical reference all scripture associated with the subject must be taken into consideration; which actually means a detailed study over a long period of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Table of Nations in Genesis 10, the Egyptians are descended from Ham (the son of Noah):

> The sons of Ham were Cush and Mizraim and Put and Canaan. - [Genesis 10:6 NASB](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%2010%3A6&version=NASB)

[Mizraim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mizraim) is the Hebrew word for the nation of Egypt, in fact a number of versions translate this verse as such, *eg*:

> The sons of Ham: Cush, Egypt, Put and Canaan. - [Genesis 10:6 NIV](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%2010%3A6&version=NIV)

Comment: This is a simplified answer to an exhaustive study of not only Genesis; but also all of the Pentateuch. Is a fitting answer to this simplified question, however.